# Camera calibration on tennis court

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have extracted the locations of all these points using a court detection model,
[tennis court points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbeuN.jpg)

I also made a tennis court in unity and mapped all of these points's positions in unity.

You can see 2D to 3D Mapped Coordinates here: https://pastebin.com/BAqUNdyu

Now I have about 25 point-to-point correspondences between 2D and 3D. I found this function to generate a camera projection matrix(from a StackOverflow thread)

```
def process():
    C = cv.initCameraMatrix2D([objPts], [imgPts], (width, height))
    print("camera matrix:")
    print(C)
    fx = C[0,0]

    # fx * tan(hfov/2) == width/2
    hfov = np.arctan(width/2 / fx) * 2
    print(f"horizontal FoV:\n\t{hfov / np.pi * 180:.2f} °")

    # x? mm focal length -> 36 mm horizontal (24 vertical)?
    fd = 36 / (np.tan(hfov/2) * 2)
    print(f"focal length (35mm equivalent):\n\t{fd:.2f} mm")

    (rv, rvec, tvec) = cv.solvePnP(objPts, imgPts, C, distCoeffs=None)
    print("tvec [m]:")
    print(tvec)
    
    return C, tvec, rvec, rv
```

and I am generating the 3D Coordinates using this function,

```
def map2Dto3D(points_2D, tvec, rvec, C, R):
    # Convert rotation vector to rotation matrix
    R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)

    # Invert the camera matrix
    C_inv = np.linalg.inv(C)

    # List to store 3D points
    points_3D = []

    # Iterate over each 2D point
    for point_2D in points_2D:
        # Convert 2D point to homogeneous coordinates
        point_2D_homo = np.array([point_2D[0], point_2D[1], 1])

        # Compute the intermediate 3D point
        intermediate_point = np.dot(np.dot(C_inv, R), point_2D_homo)

        # Compute the scale factor using the z-component of the translation vector
        scale_factor = tvec[2] / intermediate_point[2]

        # Compute the final 3D point
        point_3D = scale_factor * intermediate_point + tvec

        # Append the 3D point to the list
        points_3D.append(point_3D)

    # Write results to file
    with open("3dpoints.txt", "w") as file:
        for point_3D in points_3D:
            file.write(f"[{point_3D[0]}, {point_3D[1]}, {point_3D[2]}]\n")

    return points_3D
```

However, the 3d coordinates I am getting are looking like this,

[3d coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpo1I.png)
Obviously, something went wrong, as the 3D coordinates are not in the format I expected (X, Y, Z) and all the coordinates are the same. I am not sure what I did wrong.

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: do not provide points you can't locate properly, i.e. those that aren't on corners. -- work through the math using a single point. step by step. use a debugger. look at the values. compare to your own calculation.

Comment: I don't get everything, since we don't have a [mre]. But as far as I can see, you don't use a tennis court model in your 2d->3d process. You are just trying to invert a projection matrix. Which, by definition, can't be done (linear algebra way to say that there are many 3d points that match a given 2d point in the image. A whole line of them).

Comment: With knowledge of how the points are supposed to be located relative to each other (your knownledge of tennis court) it is feasible. The "tennis court model" is a constraint that, together with the line of possible points given by the "unprojection", should resolve to a single point (simply the fact that those points are a the ground plane should be enough). But from what I think I see (again, I can't run your code to even check the shapes of your matrix), I feel that you are not using such knowledge, and expect to translate generally speaking a 2d point into a 3d one, with the 3d->2d matrix